# GLSL Fragment Shader to intelligently tile texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

I am creating a game where I have platforms of different sizes - but always in multiplications of 8 pixels and always 8 pixels high.

All platforms use the same texture like the one here:

[image: Tiling texture image with description]

The texture is divided up into three 8x8 sections. I want to be able to "tile" this texture via the fragment shader so that the first 8 pixels are applied only at the left end - the middle 8 pixels tiles for as many pixels as the width of the geometry minus the last 8 pixels where the "end" tile is rendered. Something like this geometry which is 32 pixels wide and 8 pixels high:

[image: Tiled platform]

The framework I use does not allow setting the vertices and UVs (just a simple textured quad) so I cannot fix this in the geometry.

I get the following uniforms in the fragment shader:

- *sampler2D* 
  **u_texture** - The texture above
- *vec2*
  **u_sprite_size** - The size of the geometry I want to tile the texture in (in pixels)

.. and this varying:

- *vec2* **v_tex_coord** - The coordinates used to access the texture. These are normalized so that the point (0.0,0.0) is in the
  bottom-left corner of the texture.

It is possible to add other uniforms via code.

Can someone point me in the direction of how to create the fragment shader?

Comment: Are you asking about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES? Because they're not the same thing. Also, are you guaranteed that the size will always be a multiple of 8?

Comment: This is OpenGL-ES for starters - but I will also be porting the game to Mac so I will need a solution for OpenGL as well. Wrt to the other question, yes it will always be multiples of 8 for this game since it is tile based on an 8x8 grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem so I wrote a simple fragment shader. It is probably not the cleanest solution so you can try to optimize it.

The first thing you need is to calculate the **number of tiles** in the object (only vertically):

```
float verticalTiles = u_sprite_size.x / 8.0;
```

After that you have to calculate the **tile** you are currently processing and the **UV** for this tile. To do this you multiply the uv coordinates with the amount of vertical tiles and floor the value because you want only whole number. Then you also need to fract the value to get uv coordinates:

```
float tile = floor(verticalTiles * v_tex_coord.x);
float tileUV = fract(verticalTiles  * v_tex_coord.x); // [0; 1] for each tile
```

Now you want to apply the first 8 pixels of the texture only to the first tile and last 8 pixels to the last tile. Other tiles would have the middle 8 pixels. It can be sampled using a simple if statement. We are only calculating the `U` value because `V` won't change anyway:

```
float resultU; 

if(tile == 0.0){ 
    // If this is first tile, then we want the UV coordinates of the first 8 pixels.
    // We divide tileUV by 3 to get UV coordinates [0; 0.3333].
    resultU = tileUV / 3.0;

}else if(tile == verticalTiles - 1.0){
    // If this is last tile we do the same thing but add two thirds
    // to the coordinates to get last 8 pixels [0.6666; 1]
    resultU = tileUV / 3.0 + (2.0 / 3.0);

}else{
    // Else we want the middle 8 pixels [0.3333; 0.6666]
    resultU = tileUV / 3.0 + (1.0 / 3.0);
}
```

Then use this value to sample from the texture:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D( u_texture, vec2(resultU, v_tex_coord.y));
```

Comment: Thank you MarGenDo :) I was sort of hoping to avoid the if ... else but since performance is not impacted too negatively when I apply the shader it works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, the typical method for achieving this is to send UV coordinates along with the vertices. data. But Just to be safe, I'll reiterate. In order for texture mapping to occur texture coordinates need to be passed from the vertex shader, into the fragment shader for interpolation. Since you cannot supply the properly mapped UV coordinates, you will need to calculate them on the fly in the fragment shader which is convoluted and error prone unless done correctly. That said, consider that normalized UV coordinates range from 0-1 so that your 8x8 tile is actual {0-1}x{0-1}. For random geometry, you really need to know the width, height and world offset to successfully auto generate the UV's (without distortion).

On another hand, **and if possible**, you're best bet is to use object instancing so that you draw one square tile of any **equal** width and height so that you have four known points that you can hard code to map to UV [0-1]x[0-1]. Them just instance the same tile in lines using Model matrix offsets. Basically it's cloning the one known square geometry, and tiling the same object as much as possible. Consider all types of square (left, middle , and right), as a separate instance collection. Then the new problem will be in generating model matrices that offset the tiles in lines one after another.

This is also a very efficient way of generating a large world with relatively few triangles passed to the GPU.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. The problem is, the framework I am using does not allow me to set UVs. The object is rendered on a simple quad which means my UVs go from 0,0 bottom-left to 1,1 top-right. I get this information in the fragment shader in the varying **v_tex_coord**.  I also know the width of the object in pixels via the uniform **u_sprite_size**. I somehow need to translate this information into a vec2 that I can then use to sample the **u_texture** as I described above. Since I know the size of the object I can get the number of tiles by vec2 count = u_sprite_size / vec2(8.0, 8.0);

Comment: Understood. I'll leave the answer up just as a reference to others but it sounds that you are simply API bound. Perhaps the API provider may be a better source.